# show category after click (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this simple script:

```
var jq111 = jQuery.noConflict();

jq111( ".main-cat" ).click(function() {
  jq111( ".child" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```

This show child category when i click on `main-cat`.

Example:

> CAR
>
> - Audi <- show after click
> - Ferrari <- show after click
> - Fiat <- show after click

I have a problem that,all main category drop her child when i click one of their.

Another main category:

Bicycle, Motorcycle etc..

The categories are dynamic, all main have the same class because they are output by loop.

How can I expand only the categories within its container?

HTML:

```
 <ul class="main-cat">
 <li><a href="#">CAR</a>

 <ul class="child">
 <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Fiat</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Lamborghini</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>

 <ul class="main-cat">
 <li><a href="#">Motorcycle</a>

 <ul class="child">
 <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
```

Comment: This is not clear enough to give an answer. Additionally tou need to post the HTML code.

Comment: i update my code with html

Comment: I have posted an answer, please have a look at it.

Comment: is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much

Comment: Please consider to up vote the answer. This will be useful for other users seeking for the same, cheers :)

Comment: I need 15 reputation to vote up an answer (the site say this when i press up) :( But i have accept your Answer!

Comment: Never mind, I am always happy when I can help someone. Have nice coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ul class="main-cat">
    <li><a href="#">CAR</a>

     <ul class="child">
     <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Fiat</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lamborghini</a></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>

<ul class="main-cat">
    <li><a href="#">BICYCLE</a>

     <ul class="child">
     <li><a href="#">Bike 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Bike 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Bike 3</a></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

**NOTE:** the structure of the elements. They are wrapped in its own 'ul' tags

And your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       var jq111 = jQuery.noConflict();

       jq111('.main-cat ul').hide() //hide all by default

       jq111( ".main-cat" ).click(function() {
            jq111('.main-cat ul').hide() //this will hide the elements if one is already open
            jq111(this).find( ".child" ).show( "slow" );
       });

 });
```

The working demo is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/5j8ne1tz/

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to make a definite recommendation without see the actual HTML - but perhaps this will work?

```
    var jq111 = jQuery.noConflict();

    jq111( ".main-cat" ).click(function() {
            jq111(this).find( ".child" ).toggle( "slow" );
    });
```

That should find each `.child` element below the `.main-cat` classed element that was clicked.